# Python Pandas how to find matching values by label

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks something like this:

| mark | time | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14:22:02 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 14:22:05 | 8 | 4 |
| 2 | 14:25:02 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 14:26:05 | 4 | 7 |
| 3 | 15:12:08 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 15:12:11 | 5 | 4 |
| 3 | 15:12:15 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 15:12:17 | 8 | 4 |

I would like to output all the matches by label 1 and 3

Expected result:

Number of matches is the number of intersections with the same symbols of the label 1 and 3
That is, if there are 5 in mark 1 and Value 1 column, then it counts the entire number of intersections with mark3 in Value 1

By two columns of value

| mark | value1 | value2 | Number of matches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-3 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 1-3 | 8 | 4 | 1 |

For value 1

| mark | value1 | Number of matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-3 | 5 | 3 |
| 1-3 | 8 | 1 |

For value 2

| mark | value2 | Number of matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-3 | 2 | 2 |
| 1-3 | 4 | 2 |

Comment: Shouldn't the counts be 3 and 2 in the first output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `groupby` on the filtered DataFrame, then filter again to have a count > 1:

```
target = ['value1', 'value2']

(df.loc[df['mark'].isin([1,3])]
   .astype({'mark': 'str'})
   .groupby(target, as_index=False)
   .agg(**{'mark': ('mark', lambda g: '-'.join(dict.fromkeys(g))),
           'Num matches': ('mark', 'count')
          })
   .loc[lambda d: d['Num matches'].gt(1)]
 )
```

Output:

```
   value1  value2 mark  Num matches
0       5       2  1-3            3
2       8       4  1-3            2
```